# The difference between `ObjectClass` and `Object` in qemu

Tags: c, qemu

I am learning qemu and qom recently. I am perplexed when I meet the conception of `ObjectClass` and `Object`. I already understand that `ObjectClass` stands for *class* while `Object` means *instance of class*. However, what I want to know is What kind of information should store in `ObjectClass` and what's going on in `Object`.

As far as I am concerned, like *C++* or *Java*, *Object* just the same as what's define in *Class* and be used in real logic. In this case, *Class* seems like a template which produce *Object* the real be used.

In **qemu**, everything seems different. **We define these two in two struct**, and they have different *properties*, which leads to separation of *Class* and *Object*. Does it means I can use one `ObjectClass` to produce many `Object` that differ with each other? And secondly, why should I do this? Are there any advantages of this pattern? In detail, what's the role `ObjectClass` and `Object` plays in qemu respectively? And what about their relationship? If I want to design a new device, What should I do in initialization of `MyObjectClass` and `MyObject`?

What's more, I notice that qemu will initialize every `ObjectClass` by `TypeImpl`, which is initialized by `TypeInfo` defined by developer.

```
TypeInfo => ModuleEntry => TypeImpl => ObjectClass => Object
```

Of course they do different things. `TypeInfo` converts to `ModuleEntry` before `main` function is executed(`__attribute__((constructor))`), which contains initial functions of `ObjectClass` and `Object`. Why we need this mechanism? On the other words, what if we just create `ObjectClass` instead of create `TypeImpl` and create `ObjectClass` after that? Any advantages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of QEMU's object model (QOM), which is documented [in the developer section of the documentation](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/devel/qom.html). You should read that, and also look through include/qom/object.h for more details of the object model.

In QOM, for any class there is one class struct -- for the base Object type the class struct is ObjectClass. There are then multiple objects created at runtime, each of which is a struct Object. This applies also for subtypes of Object, like DeviceState, whose class struct is DeviceClass. The class struct holds fields which are common to every instance of that object type, notably including the function pointers which are the equivalent of methods. The object struct holds all the fields which are per-instance. Because each Object contains a pointer to the corresponding ObjectClass, you can always get from a pointer to an instance of an object to its class information.

Because we're implementing an object-oriented model in C, we have to have everything be explicit -- in C++ and Java, because the object model is part of the language the compiler can sort out under the hood a lot of the things QOM has to manage manually with class structs and object structs and so on.

More generally, if your aim is "write a new device" I would recommend that you do not spend any time looking into the internals of the QOM implementation. Instead you should look at how other devices similar to yours are implemented and at what the patterns of code are that they use to declare and use a new device type.

Comment: yes, I had read the QOM document. But I think it don't explain the vary detail in qom. For instance, **what's properties and how it work in qom?** and **if TypeImpl makes ObjectClass, why ObjectClass stores an TypeImpl?** Of course I can imitate some device in order to make my own, but isn't  there have a universal concept or pattern to be learned?

Comment: And as you said, `DeviceState` is the Object of `DeviceClass` and I can see in `edu device(hw/misc/edu.c)` that `edu` is the subclass of `PCIDevice`. However, when I check `PCIDevice`, I found that *ObjectClass* should be `PCIDeviceClass` rather than `PCIDevice`. Does it means a ObjectClass of device(`EduState` in edu.c) is containing a *Object* or `EduState` should not be a *ObjectClass*? Neither explanation presuaded me...

Comment: EduState is-a PCIDevice is-a DeviceState is-a Object. There is no class struct for EduState because it doesn't need one (it would be empty); the class struct for PCIDevice is PCIDeviceClass; the class struct for DeviceState is DeviceClass; the class struct for Object is ObjectClass.

Comment: Then why we don't define `EduDeviceClass` with its detail fields that now we write in `EduState` and define a `EduState` includes only `EduDeviceClass`? On the other words, why we make an empty `EduDeviceClass` here?

Comment: What's more, what also confused me is Document says: *The first member of this object(`struct Object`) is a pointer to a #ObjectClass.* And it do have `ObjectClass` as the first member. However, what happens in `DeviceState` is **the first member is `Object` rather than `DeviceClass`**. It seems like there are two path, one is the chain of succession of `ObjectClass` and the other is for `Object`. That looks different with what documents says.

Comment: The first member of Object is a *pointer* to ObjectClass. This is because Object is the base class. The first member of DeviceState is not a pointer, it is an embedded Object. This is because DeviceState is a derived class (that is, you can cast a DeviceState pointer to an Object pointer). So the thing at offset 0 of DeviceState is in fact a pointer to ObjectClass, because that's the first thing in the embedded Object struct.